# How to convert java encoding of UTF-8 characters to HTML encoding?

Tags: java, utf-8

Is there any Java utility or library to convert Java UTF-8 encoding to HTML encoding?

Example:

For the [substitute](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001a/index.htm) character, Java encoding is `"\u001A"` and HTML encoding is `&#26;`.

How to convert Java encoding to HTML encoding?

Comment: `\u001A` is not UTF-8.  It is a Java Unicode escape.

Comment: Please refer this link. http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm @StephenC

Comment: The UTF-8 is the right hand column of that table!  Look up UTF-8 and Unicode in Wikipedia (or on http://unicode.org) if you want to really understand what the terms mean.

Comment: Hex 0x1A is decimal 26.  `"\u001A"` is a string with a single `char` whose value is 0x001A. Simply take that `char` and output its numeric value, prefixed with `&#` and suffixed with `;`.

Comment: You would probably benefit most by using a library that allows you to construct an HTML document as an object and can serialize (write) it to a file or stream using a character encoding that you specify.

Answer (score 2):

Apache offers [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html).

It contains escape/unescape Java.

As well as escape/unescape html.

Using String in the middle, you should be able to accomplice the conversion that you want.